# Building cmake with non-default GCC uses system libstdc++

Tags: gcc, cmake, libstdc++

I'm trying to compile CMake using a non-default GCC installed in /usr/local/gcc530, on Solaris 2.11.

I have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc530/lib/sparcv9`

Bootstrap proceeds fine, bootstrapped cmake successfully compiles various object files, but when it tries to link the real `cmake` (and other executables), I get pages of "undefined reference" errors to various standard library functions, because, as running the link command manually with `-Wl,-verbose` shows, the linker links with `/usr/lib/64/libstdc++.so` of the system default, much older GCC.

This is because apparently CMake tries to find curses/ncurses libraries (even if I tell it `BUILD_CursesDialog:BOOL=OFF`), finds them in /usr/lib/64, and adds `-L/usr/lib/64` to build/Source/CMakeFiles/cmake.dir/link.txt, which causes the linker to use libstdc++.so from there, and not my actual GCC's own.

I found a workaround: I can get the path to proper libraries from `$CC -m64 -print-file-name=libstdc++.so` then put it with `-L` into LDFLAGS when running ./configure, and all works well then.

Is there a less hacky way? It's really weird that I can't tell GCC to prioritize its own libraries.

Also, is there some way to have CMake explain where different parts of a resulting command line came from?

Comment: Why `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc530/lib/sparcv9` instead of just `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc530/lib` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc530/lib64` ? What is this `sparcv9` directory anyway?

Comment: @oLen: Solaris stuff (it actually runs on a SPARC CPU), it's not relevant, I don't have a problem running compiled binaries.